# Please help me to find out exact meaning of this sentence

Tags: meaning

"Different forms of life at different levels of existence make up the teeming denizens of this earth of ours"

I have searched for the new words used in this

Teeming : be full of or swarming with.
Denizens : a person, animal, or plant that lives or is found in a particular place.

But not able to get exact idea of this sentence.

Comment: *Earth has lots of lifeforms.*

Answer (score 1):

> "Different forms of life at different levels of existence make up the teeming denizens of this earth of ours"

**Break down** - this Earth of ours is made up of (or filled with)

- people,
- animals,
- plants, etc

and all these denizens (or [inhabitants](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/inhabitant)) are:

- different forms of life (people, animals, plants, organisms, living things, etc)
- at different levels of existence (some species are more evolved than other species, some species are dying off or will be replaced by others, etc).

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind the increasing population of this world is a change in various forms of life beings at multiple situations and conditions of cosmos.

Comment: There is no part of the quote that talks about an increasing population.

Comment: what about teeming denizens (anything that populates or exists on earth)

Comment: Teeming denizens means the world is full of people/animals/etc.  It does not mean the number of denizens is increasing.  Just because my cup of water is teeming does not mean that more water is being poured into it.  It just means my cup of water is very full.